# Autostart in redshift is not working

Tags: 14.10, redshift

Although I did check autostart in redshift, I have to restart the program if I turned off my computer. Why is this? The setting is marked in redshift and it is filed under startup applications.

Comment: If you want to know why a feature of redshift doesn't work, contact the developer/maintainer. Here, we can help you get it autostarted: possible duplicate of [How do I start applications automatically on login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: There is an option for autostart in the toolbar-icon, but it doesn't seem to work.